# Xml Deserializer - unexpected end of file

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, tcpclient, xmlserializer

I am writing a server - to many clients architecture based application.Server is multithread - each  client has its own thread where communication is performed .I use TCpClient to perform communication . I keep getting strange error :unexpected end of file occured  missing close tags" when i try to deserialize message from read from stream . If message is short enough it works corectly. I tried to make my buffers bigger but it didin't give any result . I would appreciate any help.

**Deserialization**

```
  public static Message GetResponse(string messageString)
    {
        string rootNodeName = String.Empty;
        Message message=null;
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(messageString))
        {
            return null;
        }
        Type T = null;
        XmlSerializer serializer = null;

        using (XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(messageString)))
        {
            if (xmlReader.MoveToContent() == XmlNodeType.Element)
                rootNodeName = xmlReader.Name;

            T = ReturnMessageType(rootNodeName);
            Contract.Assert(T != null); 
             serializer = new XmlSerializer(T);
        }
        if (serializer != null)
        {
            using (var reader = new StringReader(messageString))
                message = (Message)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        }


        return message;
    }
```

**Client code**

```
  public void PerformCommuncation(Message mes, CancellationToken tocken)
    {
        try
        {
            using (TcpClient client = new TcpClient(Adress, Port))
            {
                string message = String.Empty;

                using (var stream = client.GetStream())
                {
                    if (tocken.IsCancellationRequested)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("ZAMYKAM TASKA");
                        return;
                    }

                    var str = Message.Serialize(mes, stream);
                    stream.Flush();

                    byte[] data2 = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize];
                    StringBuilder fullReply = new StringBuilder();
                    int numberOfBytesRead = 1;
                  stream.ReadTimeout = 4000;



                    try {
                        while (numberOfBytesRead > 0)

                        {

                            numberOfBytesRead = stream.Read(data2, 0, data2.Length);

                            fullReply.AppendFormat("{0}", Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data2, 0, numberOfBytesRead));
                            if (fullReply.Length == 0) continue;

                        }
                    }
                    catch(Exception)
                    {

                    }

                    var mesagesList = new List<Message>();

                    if (fullReply != null)
                    {

                        var messages = fullReply.ToString().Split((char)23);
                        int size = messages.Length;

                        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
                        {

                            var messageType = MessageManager.GetResponse(messages[i]);
                            if (messageType == null)
                                continue;
                            Console.WriteLine();
                            Console.WriteLine("RECEIVED MESSAGE: {0}", messageType.GetType());
                            Console.WriteLine();
                            if (messageType != null)
                            {
                                mesagesList.Add(messageType);
                                Console.WriteLine("DODAJE NA LISTE :{0}", messageType.GetType());
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if (ComponentType == ComponentType.CommunicationServer && mesagesList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.GetType().ToString().Contains("RegisterResponse")) != null)
                    {
                        mesagesList.Reverse();
                    }
                    foreach (var resp in mesagesList)
                    {
                        dynamic T = this;
                        Message[] messages = null;


                        resp.SenderType = this.ComponentType;
                        resp.Sender = ((IPEndPoint)client.Client.RemoteEndPoint).Address.ToString();
                        if (resp.SenderType == ComponentType.CommunicationServer && String.IsNullOrEmpty(((ICommunicationServer)this).MyAdress))
                            ((ICommunicationServer)this).MyAdress = resp.Sender;
                        messages = resp.Run(T);

                        if (messages != null && messages.Length > 0)
                            foreach (var msg in messages)
                            {
                                PerformCommuncation(msg, tocken);
                            }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (ArgumentNullException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ArgumentNullException: {0}", e);
        }
        catch (SocketException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("SocketException: {0}", e);
            // EstablishConnectionAfterCSBreakdown(msg);
            RecreateConnection(mes);
        }

    }
```

**Server code**

```
 private void ThreadProc(object obj)
    {
        String data = String.Empty;
        {
            using (var client = (TcpClient)obj)
            {
                using (var stream = client.GetStream())
                {
                    byte[] data2 = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize];

                    StringBuilder fullReply = new StringBuilder();

                    int numberOfBytesRead = 2;
                    stream.ReadTimeout = 1000;

                    try {
                        do
                        {
                            if (numberOfBytesRead <= 1) continue;

                            numberOfBytesRead = stream.Read(data2, 0, data2.Length);


                            fullReply.AppendFormat("{0}", Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data2, 0, numberOfBytesRead));

                            if (fullReply.Length == 0) continue;

                            log.Info("Odebrano wiadomość");
                        } while (stream.DataAvailable);
                    }

                    catch(Exception)
                    { Console.WriteLine(" EXCEPTION ON read  !!!"); };

                    var mesagesList = new List<Message>();

                    {

                        var messageString = fullReply.ToString();

                          var messageType = MessageManager.GetResponse(messageString);

                        dynamic T = this;
                        if (messageType != null)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("ODEBRANO: ", messageType);
                            messageType.SenderType = ComponentType.CommunicationServer;
                            messageType.Sender = ((IPEndPoint)client.Client.RemoteEndPoint).Address.ToString();
                            var response = messageType.Run(T);

                            log.Info("SERWER ODPOWIADA: ");

                            if (response != null)
                                mesagesList.AddRange(response);
                        }
                    }


                  for(int i=0;i<mesagesList.Count;i++)
                    {
                        var r = mesagesList[i];
                        if (r == null) continue;
                        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(r.GetType());
                        try
                        {
                            serializer.Serialize(stream, r);
                            stream.Flush();
                        }
                        catch (Exception e)
                        {
                            serializer.Serialize(stream, r);
                        }

                        if (mesagesList.Count > 1 && i!=mesagesList.Count-1)
                            stream.Write(new byte[] { 23 }, 0, 1);
                    }

                }
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: A TCP datagram has maximum number of bytes of ~1500. When reading you need to read to end of data, but a connection which is a stream has no end unless the connection closes.  The best solution is to insert a byte count at the beginning of the message, then have receive end read the number of bytes. You are getting the error because you are trying to parse the xml data before you have gotten all the bytes. So first get the bytes which may be in multiple datagrams, then parse the xml.  Closing the connection doesn't always work because the connection can close before all the data gets received.

Comment: Is there any other way to check if I have proper message than sending its  size ? My messages have their schemas which I can not change .

Comment: You can use a terminating character at end of stream.  The size would be sent as the first characters and you would remove these characters before you parsed the xml so it would not effect the schema.